# Prove that one set S that is a subset of to the set of the natural numbers is, in reality, the proper set of natural numbers

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Considering the Well-Ordered Principle to prove the following:

$$
\text{Be } \mathbb{S} \text{ a set that belongs to the set of natural numbers, i.e. } \mathbb{S} \subset \mathbb{N}.\\ \text{ If } 0 \in \mathbb{S} \wedge (\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \{0,1,2,\cdots,k\} \subset \mathbb{S} \rightarrow k+1 \in S) \rightarrow \mathbb{S} = \mathbb{N}
$$

I did a proof and I would like to know if it is in a good shape.

Proof reached:

> Let's prove the stated proposition by contradiction. Therefore, we assume that 
>   $$
> 0 \in \mathbb{S} \wedge (\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \{0,1,2,\cdots,k\} \subset \mathbb{S} \rightarrow k+1 \in S)
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \mathbb{S} \neq \mathbb{N}
> $$
>   are **true**. Since $\mathbb{S} \neq \mathbb{N}$, there is a not empty set that follows from
>   $$
> \mathbb{N} - \mathbb{S}.
> $$
>   Be $\mathbb{W}$ the set resulting from the operation above. The set $\mathbb{W}$ if formed by the elements that are presentes in $\mathbb{N}$ and not in $\mathbb{S}$ and, by the Well-Ordered Principle, it has a minor element. Let $m$ be the minor element in question. We have that
>   $$
> 0 \in \mathbb{S}
> $$
>   and, therefore, $m > 0$. With $k$ as reference, we have that
>   $$
> \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \{0,1,2,\cdots,k\} \subset \mathbb{S}
> $$
>   and, therefore, $m > k$ or $m \geq k+1$. But, in this situation, $k+1 \in \mathbb{S}$ and $m > k +1$. With $k+1$ as reference, we have that
>   $$
> \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \{0,1,2,\cdots,k, k+1\} \subset \mathbb{S}
> $$
>   and, therefore, $m > k + 1$ or $m \geq k+2$. But, in this situation, $k+2 \in \mathbb{S}$ and $m > k + 2$. Well, from the exposed, one can see that m is not a minor value, since it is possible to always find a value that requires, for $\mathbb{S} \neq \mathbb{N}$ hold,to $m$ be bigger than it last possible minor value. This contradict the Well-Ordered principle and, therefore, proofs that $\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{N}$ for the situation stated.

Comment: Isn't that just the $5^{\text{th}}$ Peano's axiom of induction? You could use the [successor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) or [_Zorn's lemma_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). Also, you could reduce the number of words and just write $\Bbb W=\Bbb N\setminus\Bbb S$.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1780585/721644)  might be useful. So, your proof relies on the fact a natural number has **finitely many predecessors** and **infinitely many successors**.